# dynamic values to radio buttons

Tags: javascript, aura, radio-button

Im getting a http response which contains names of the groups.
Im trying to show the groups on the aura component and also do further operations.

```
apex code

@AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getGroups(){
        string names;
        List<String> Groupnames = new List<String>();
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('X-ChatWorkToken',key);
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms');
        HttpResponse res = http.send(request);
        LIST<Object> arr = (LIST<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        for(integer i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
            Map<String, Object> firstMap = (Map<String, Object>)arr[i];
            names = (String)firstMap.get('name');
            Groupnames.add(names);
        }
        return Groupnames;
    }
```

javascript

```
listofgroup:function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get("c.getGroups");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                let groupValues = [];
                var res = response.getReturnValue();
                res.forEach((value)=>{
                    groupValues.push({label:value,value:value});
                });
                component.set("v.lstGroup",groupValues);
           }
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

aura component

```
<aura:component controller="testevent"  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <lightning:button label="search" onclick="{!c.listofgroup}"/> 
        <lightning:radioGroup
            label="Chatwork Rooms"
            options="{!v.lstGroup}"
            value="{!v.lstGroup}"  
            type="radio"
            />
</p>
</lightning:card>    
</aura:component>
```

i tried the above code but not able to get the result

Comment: first this is that you need separate attribute for "value", i.e. string attribute. Second question is, have you created <aura:attribute for `v.lstGroup`?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion....thats working....Thank you @ytiq....

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this is that you need separate attribute for "value", i.e. string attribute. Second question is, have you created <aura:attribute for `v.lstGroup`?